# vlookup to update table

Tags: excel, function, vlookup

I can't manage to find the answer anywhere so here it goes:

I am sending out surveys to clients, i have a table with A1: Client's email; B1: email working or not; C1: Comments

I have another table that are the emails of clients that don't work:
A1: client's email; B1: comments

I want to update table 1 so that if a client's email in table 1 is also in table 2 it is assigned the corresponding comment from table 2.

From what i understand vlookup function can do this but i can't manage to get it working.

Thank you very much,

Dan

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly your problem, you must add a 4th column in your 1st table. This new column will display the comment from table 2. You could name it "Comments from table 2" for example.
Type this formula in it:

```
=IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP(A2,Sheet2!A$2:B$999,2,FALSE)),"",VLOOKUP(A2,Sheet2!A$2:B$999,2,FALSE))
```

This is what I have, finally:

Sheet 1

```
| Email  | Working | Comment | Comment from table 2 |
----------------------------------------------------
| Email1 |   Yes   | Good    |                      |
----------------------------------------------------
| Email2 |   No    | Bad     |  Arghhhh             |
----------------------------------------------------
```

Sheet 2

```
| Email  | Comment |
--------------------
| Email2 | Arghhhh |
--------------------
```